# java callable statement .next

Tags: java

I have this right now:

```
public java.util.Vector getList() {

    java.util.Vector myuserList = new java.util.Vector();
    DbUtil db = null;
    java.sql.CallableStatement cstmt = null;
    ResultSet rset = null;


        db = new DbUtil();
        cstmt = db.prepareCall("{ call sample.user.get_user_list(?, ?, ?) }");

        cstmt.registerOutParameter(1,OracleTypes.CHAR);
        cstmt.registerOutParameter(2,OracleTypes.VARCHAR);
        cstmt.registerOutParameter(3,OracleTypes.CURSOR);

            cstmt.execute();

        }

        rset = (ResultSet) cstmt.getObject(3);
        if (rset != null) {
            while(rset.next()) {
                userBean myuser = new userBean();
                myuser.setuserid(rset.getString(1).trim());
                myuser.setuserName(rset.getString(2));


                myuserList.addElement(myuser);
            }
        }
                return myuserList;
             }
```

I want to get one more string ssn under my while(rset.next()).. when i just add this  `myuser.setuserSSN(rset.getString(3));` under  `myuser.setuserName(rset.getString(2));` its giving me error.. i have already updated my procedure to get user SSN so how can i get that ssn number here.. what do i have to modify.. one more thing i am getting all three userid, username and userSSN by using cursor `cstmt.registerOutParameter(3,OracleTypes.CURSOR);` first two callable statment are for exceptions in the procedure.. please help

here is the error i get..

```
compile:
 [exec] com\javabean\userBean.java:188: cannot resolve symbol
 [exec] symbol  : variable myuser
 [exec] location: class com.javabean.userBean
 [exec]                                     myuser.setuserSSN(rset.getString(3));
 [exec]                                         ^
 [exec] 1 error
```

Comment: There's still not enough information about the error.  Please show us what's above what you posted here.

Comment: The first line of the error is missing.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `userBean` class doesn't have a method `setuserSSN`. Using conventional case, this would be written as 'setUserSSN' (upper-case `U`). If there is a `setuserSSN` method, check that it takes a single `String` argument.

Unless you have some established convention, `userBean` is probably better renamed to `UserBean` since classes conventionally start in upper-case.

Comment: i already have all this:
`public userBean() {
  userid = new String();
  userName = new String();
  userSSN = new String();
 }

 public String getuserid() {
  return userid;
 }

 public void setuserid(String s) {
  userid = s;
 }
  
 public String getuserName() {
  return userName;
 }

 public void setuserName(String s) {
  userName = s;
 }

 public String getuserSSN() {
  return userSSN;
 }

 public void setuserSSN(String s) {
  userSSN = s;
 }`

Comment: Ah, I see. Rechecking the OP, the error is complaining about `myuser`. Are you adding the setuserSSN call directly under the other calls? Make sure you don't have any closing braces in between. It looks like `myuser` is out of scope.

Comment: yes, i am not changing anything in there.. if i remove userSSN.. it works perfectly fine

Answer (score 0):

You are not selecting the SSN from the Stored Procedure.  You have three out parameters, 1 = user id, 2 = user name, 3 = cursor.  When you try to add `(rset.getString(3));` it is trying to set the cursor to a string and pass it into the set SSN method.  Try this:

```
public java.util.Vector getList() { 

java.util.Vector myuserList = new java.util.Vector(); 
DbUtil db = null; 
java.sql.CallableStatement cstmt = null; 
ResultSet rset = null; 


    db = new DbUtil(); 
    cstmt = db.prepareCall("{ call sample.user.get_user_list(?, ?, ?, ?) }"); 

    cstmt.registerOutParameter(1,OracleTypes.CHAR); 
    cstmt.registerOutParameter(2,OracleTypes.VARCHAR); 
    cstmt.registerOutParameter(3,OracleTypes.VARCHAR);
    cstmt.registerOutParameter(4,OracleTypes.CURSOR); 

        cstmt.execute(); 

    } 

    rset = (ResultSet) cstmt.getObject(4); 
    if (rset != null) { 
        while(rset.next()) { 
            userBean myuser = new userBean(); 
            myuser.setuserid(rset.getString(1).trim()); 
            myuser.setuserName(rset.getString(2)); 
            myuser.setuserSSN(rset.getString(3));

            myuserList.addElement(myuser); 
        } 
    } 
            return myuserList; 
         }
```

and make sure the Stored Procedure selects the SSN.

I am just learning how to use the Stored Procedures myself, but when using a query string you reference the returned fields by name.  I have not mastered this yet, but I think you can just return the cursor and then set your userBean variables like this: `myuser.setuserid(rset.getString("userID").trim()); myuser.setuserName(rset.getString("username"));` etc.